# Is it possible to create a cluster in Container Engine with Cloud Deployment Manager?

Tags: deployment, cloud, containers

"Supported resource types and properties" in https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/configuration/create-configuration-file has a "container.v1beta1.cluster", but the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

That link is fixed now: [Google Container Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/)

The Cloud Deployment Manager uses the underlying APIs to do its work, so if the API exists, you should be able to use the Cloud Deployment Manager to do it. Quoting the docs:

*Remember that Deployment Manager uses the underlying APIs of Google Cloud Platform services to manage resources in your deployment. If an API doesn't support a certain action, Deployment Manager cannot perform that action either. For example, Deployment Manager can only update an existing resource if there is an update method in the corresponding API.*

So you should be able to create a cluster with the Cloud Deployment Manager.